# Give an analyze an O(n) algorithm to check for nuts/bolts matches in sorted arrays

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, big-o

I have a collection of n nuts, and a collection of n bolts, both arranged in increasing order of size. I need to give an O(n) algorithm to check if 
a nut and bolt have the same size. Nut sizes are in an array NUTS[1..n]
bolt sizes are in an array BOLTS[1...n]

I don't need to find all matches, just stop the algorithm even if one match is found. Here what my psuedocode looks like so far

```
 for each n in NUTS 
     for each b in BOLTS 
          if BOLTS[i] == NUTS[i]
              break;
```

So for each nut, I'm searching through all the bolts. This is O(n^2), How would I make this O(n)? My understanding is I would probably need to have just one for loop to do this. Sorry my understanding is a little shaky

Comment: This is not a O(n) it is O(n^2) in worst case

Comment: How would I make this an O(n), by making only one for loop?

Comment: Iterate both arrays in parallel (make two index variables).

Comment: Thanks, so I would have two index variables in the for loop header, then in the body of the loops just match to see if BOLTS[b] == NUTS[n] ? Then call it a day?

Comment: Start with `BOLTS[i]`, and iterate through `NUTS` until `NUTS[j]` is equal to or larger than `BOLTS[i]`. If `NUTS[j]` is larger, then continue with next `BOLTS[i]` until `BOLTS[i] >= NUTS[j]`. This way you will end up with `n+n` in the worst case, which is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can step through the two arrays in the same loop, but using two separate index variables. You always increment the index variable for which the array value is smaller. If neither is smaller, they're equal and you've found a match.

```
i = 0;
j = 0;
while (i < n and j < n) {
    if (NUTS[i] < BOLTS[j]) {
        i++;
    } else if (NUTS[i] > BOLTS[j]) {
        j++;
    } else {
        return true;  // found a match
    }
}
return false;  // found nothing
```

The best case is when `NUTS[0] == BOLTS[0]`, because then you enter the final `else` clause and return `true` immediately.

The worst case is when you never enter the final `else` clause, because then you have to iterate the loop all the way to the end. This happens if you always take the first or second `if` clause, incrementing either `i` or `j`. In the worst case you alternate between incrementing `i` and `j`, making both of them grow as slowly as possible. This leads to a worst case of `2*n` steps before at least one variable exceeds `n`.

Therefore this algorithm is in O(2*n), which is O(n).

Comment: This looks good, how would I do this using a for loop itireation?

Comment: @Demon213 In what language?

Comment: Java. The only thing I would need to know if if the bolts and nuts are the same size, I wouldn't need to check if one is larger than the other and fall through to an else statement right?

Comment: so something like this:   
        for(int bolt = 0, int nut = 0; bolt < n; bolt++,nut ++){
                 if BOLTS[bolt] == NUTS[nut]
                            return True;
           }

Comment: @Demon213 Fails on `BOLTS = { 0, 1 }; NUTS = { 1, 2 };`.

Comment: How would I correct that failure, I'm not seeing it still

Comment: @Demon213 By using the algorithm from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The pseudo-code shared will take O(n^2) in worst case, which is when there is no matching pair.
However you can speed this up to O(nlogn) by using binary search, as the arrays are in sorted order.

```
foreach A in nuts:
 if binarysearch ( Bolts,  Bolts+n , A)
  break;
```

Also you can speed this upto O(n) as well using two pointers one in each array and increment them accordingly.

```
 Bolt_index = Nut_index = 0
 while ( Bolt_Index < Bolts.size && Nut_Index < Nuts.Size) 
      while( Bolt_Index < Bolts.Size && Bolts[Bolt_index] < Nuts[Nut_Index]  )
      Bolt_index++ ;
      while( Nut_Index < Nuts.Size && Nuts[Nut_index] < Bolts[Bolt_Index] )
      Nut_index++ ;
      if  Bolt_Index< Bolts.Size && Nut_Index < Nuts.Size &&  Bolts[Bolt_Index] == Nuts[Nut_Index] 
       Match_found// break 
      else 
        Nut_Index++ // increment either Nut_Index or Bolt_Index
```

Comment: I will add the constraints checks

Comment: @melpomene corrected, however i was just giving idea to the op, on how to use the the two indexes, i am sure one should keep checks on the bounds while implementing it.